# My alert box isn't working

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, alert

For the 2 alerts (they are the same) "alert("The pizzas you ordered are: " +fullOrder)" They don't actually run properly. Everything runs fine until I get to the alerts, then they just don't show up. (They are linked to the array, so I think it might be something to do with that.

So, does anyone know what I've done wrong? I have a faint idea of what needs to be done but don't know how to go about it. The local variable in function order() var fullOrder needs to go into the other function calculate(). Please help!!

```html
<html>
<script>

//Global variables
var totalNumber = 0;   // Total number of pizzas ordered
 var pizzaPrice = 9.50;   // price of plain pizza
 var pizzaPriceGourmet = 15.50;  //price of gourmet pizza
 var orderTotalPrice = 0;   // total cost of order
 var pizzaDeliveryPrice = 5; // price for pizza delivery
 var FullOrder = 0; // number of pizza's ordered
 var customerName = prompt("Please enter your name.") //prompt to get the customers name
 var customerNumber = prompt("Please enter your phone number.") //prompt to get the customers number
{
 if ( isNaN(customerNumber) || customerNumber < 8400000 || customerNumber > 999999999 ) {          // Checks if customerNumber is greater than 9999999
      alert("Please enter a 7-digit telephone number between 8600000 - 9999999 Select the 'cancel order' button and enter a valid telephone number!");   // asks customer to enter a valid telephone number
} else 
   alert("Lets continue!");   // Continues to main website
}


order();//call order

calculate(totalGourmet,totalPlain);// while calling
 
function order()
{
  var pizza = new Array()
  pizza[0] = document.form.hawaiian.value                //allocates type of pizza in array
  pizza[0] = Number(pizza[0])                           //converts to number value
  pizza[1] = document.form.cheese.value                 //allocates type of pizza in array            
  pizza[1] = Number(pizza[1])                            //converts to number value
  pizza[2] = document.form.veggie.value                //allocates type of pizza in array
  pizza[2] = Number(pizza[2])                            //converts to number value
  pizza[3] = document.form.supreme.value                //allocates type of pizza in array
  pizza[3] = Number(pizza[3])                            //converts to number value
  pizza[4] = document.form.pepperoni.value                //allocates type of pizza in array
  pizza[4] = Number(pizza[4])                            //converts to number value
  pizza[5] = document.form.meatlovers.value                //allocates type of pizza in array
  pizza[5] = Number(pizza[5])                            //converts to number value
  pizza[6] = document.form.chicken.value                //allocates type of pizza in array
  pizza[6] = Number(pizza[6])                            //converts to number value
  pizza[7] = document.form.prawn.value                //allocates type of pizza in array
  pizza[7] = Number(pizza[7])                            //converts to number value

  totalPlain = pizza[0] + pizza[1] + pizza[2] + pizza[3] + pizza[4];
  totalGourmet = pizza[5] + pizza[6] + pizza[7];

  var totalNumber = totalGourmet + totalPlain

  var fullOrder = alert("You have ordered: " + "\n" +        <----- I NEED THIS
         "Hawaiian Pizza ($9.50): " + pizza [0] + "\n" +
         "Cheese Pizza ($9.50): " + pizza [1] + "\n" +
         "Veggie Pizza ($9.50): " + pizza [2] + "\n" + 
         "Supreme Pizza ($9.50): " + pizza [3] + "\n" +
         "Pepperoni Pizza ($9.50): " + pizza [4] + "\n" +
         "Meat-Lovers Pizza ($15.50): " + pizza [5] + "\n" +
         "Chicken Pizza ($15.50): " + pizza [6] + "\n" +
         "Prawn Pizza ($15.50): " + pizza [7]);  
   

  if (totalNumber >12) {          // Limit for total amount of Pizzas ordered
      alert("There is a limit of 12 pizzas per order. - PRESS 'Prevent this page from creating     additional dialogs' THEN PRESS 'cancel order' AND THEN RE-ORDER! - Current total is: " +totalNumber);
  } else 
      alert("Total number of pizzas ordered: " + totalNumber); //Total amount of pizzas ordered
  calculate(totalGourmet,totalPlain)  //Begins calculation function
}


function calculate(totalGourmet,totalPlain)    //Function for the cost of the order
{
    orderTotalPrice = (totalPlain*pizzaPrice + totalGourmet*pizzaPriceGourmet);  //order total+ amount of pizzas ordered * pizza price
    var pizzaDelivery = prompt('Would you like your order to be delivered for $5, or for pick up?    -Type in "1" for delivery, and "0" for pickup.') //asks if you want your order to be delivered or pickup
    orderTotalPrice = (orderTotalPrice + (pizzaDelivery*pizzaDeliveryPrice)); // calculates the total cost with/without the delivery cost
    alert("Total cost of pizzas is: $" + orderTotalPrice.toFixed(2) );  //Display order cost as "$"0.00 (2 decimal points)
    if (pizzaDelivery == '1'){
        var response = prompt("Please enter your address: ")
        alert("Your pizza should be delivered within the next 25 minutes, to this address:   " +response)
         alert("Thank you for ordering with Pete's Pizzas " +customerName)
         alert("If anything goes wrong we will contact you on your number: " +customerNumber)
   alert("The pizzas you ordered are: " +fullOrder) <----TO BE HERE
         alert("Your order details are: " +customerName +"\n" +customerNumber +"\n" +response)
         alert("To exit, just click 'ok' and then close down the program!")
    } else if (pizzaDelivery == '0'){
         alert("Your order will be ready for pickup in 15 minutes!")
         alert("Thank you for ordering with Pete's Pizzas " +customerName)
         alert("If anything goes wrong we will contact you on your number: " +customerNumber)
   alert("The pizzas you ordered are: " +fullOrder) <----TO BE HERE
         alert("Your order details are: " +customerName +"\n" +customerNumber)
         alert("To exit, just click 'ok' and then close down the program!")
    }
}

</script>

<body>
<h1> Welcome to Pete's Pizza! </h1>
<p> Please follow the prompts to place your order. </p>
<h2> Menu: </h2>
<h3>($9.50) Hawaiian, Cheese, Veggie, supreme, pepperoni.</h3>
<h3>($15.50) meat-lovers, chicken, prawn. </h3>
<p><b>BE AWARE</b> that there is a $5 charge for deliveries. </p>
<p> (Please note : Maximum 12 pizzas per Order ) </p>

<form name ="form">                              
     
<input type="text" name= "hawaiian" > Hawaiian Pizza <br>
<input type="text" name= "cheese" > Cheese Pizza <br>
<input type="text" name= "veggie" > Veggie Pizza <br>
<input type="text" name= "supreme" > Supreme Pizza <br>
<input type="text" name= "pepperoni" > Pepperoni Pizza <br>
<input type="text" name= "meatlovers" > MeatLovers Pizza <br>
<input type="text" name= "chicken" > Chicken Pizza <br>
<input type="text" name= "prawn" > Prawn Pizza <br>

<input type="button" value="order now" onClick="order()">
<input type="button" value="cancel order" onClick="window.location.reload()">
</form>



<i> If you need to cancel the order press the 'Prevent this page from creating     additional dialogs' button, then press the "cancel order" button. (This will take you back to the begging of the program.)  </i>
</body>   
    
</html>
```

Comment: First, fix the syntax error

Comment: have a look in you browser console, you probably have a js error where that extra opening bracket is

Comment: After fixing the syntax errors, how do I use the variable fullOrder from function order() and put it into function calculate() and still keep the order details?

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned by @Weedoze, you've got some syntax errors in your code. Solving them just fixed the issue. You may check the running code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/f1h55q6o/). To be more precise, there are several usages of this line:

```
 <----- I NEED THIS
```

To prevent syntax errors in future builds, you may use a proper IDE or just a texteditor including syntax highlighting.

Comment: Ahh yes I was supposed to remove the <---comments thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Commenting on javascript and html is different.

```html
<html>
<script>

//Global variables
var totalNumber = 0;   // Total number of pizzas ordered
 var pizzaPrice = 9.50;   // price of plain pizza
 var pizzaPriceGourmet = 15.50;  //price of gourmet pizza
 var orderTotalPrice = 0;   // total cost of order
 var pizzaDeliveryPrice = 5; // price for pizza delivery
 var FullOrder = 0; // number of pizza's ordered
 var customerName = prompt("Please enter your name.") //prompt to get the customers name
 var customerNumber = prompt("Please enter your phone number.") //prompt to get the customers number
{
 if ( isNaN(customerNumber) || customerNumber < 8400000 || customerNumber > 999999999 ) {          // Checks if customerNumber is greater than 9999999
      alert("Please enter a 7-digit telephone number between 8600000 - 9999999 Select the 'cancel order' button and enter a valid telephone number!");      // asks customer to enter a valid telephone number
} else  
    alert("Lets continue!");      // Continues to main website
}


order();//call order

calculate(totalGourmet,totalPlain);// while calling
 
function order()
{
  var pizza = new Array()
  pizza[0] = document.form.hawaiian.value                //allocates type of pizza in array
  pizza[0] = Number(pizza[0])                           //converts to number value
  pizza[1] = document.form.cheese.value                 //allocates type of pizza in array            
  pizza[1] = Number(pizza[1])                            //converts to number value
  pizza[2] = document.form.veggie.value                //allocates type of pizza in array
  pizza[2] = Number(pizza[2])                            //converts to number value
  pizza[3] = document.form.supreme.value                //allocates type of pizza in array
  pizza[3] = Number(pizza[3])                            //converts to number value
  pizza[4] = document.form.pepperoni.value                //allocates type of pizza in array
  pizza[4] = Number(pizza[4])                            //converts to number value
  pizza[5] = document.form.meatlovers.value                //allocates type of pizza in array
  pizza[5] = Number(pizza[5])                            //converts to number value
  pizza[6] = document.form.chicken.value                //allocates type of pizza in array
  pizza[6] = Number(pizza[6])                            //converts to number value
  pizza[7] = document.form.prawn.value                //allocates type of pizza in array
  pizza[7] = Number(pizza[7])                            //converts to number value

  totalPlain = pizza[0] + pizza[1] + pizza[2] + pizza[3] + pizza[4];
  totalGourmet = pizza[5] + pizza[6] + pizza[7];

  var totalNumber = totalGourmet + totalPlain

  var fullOrder = alert("You have ordered: " + "\n" +        
         "Hawaiian Pizza ($9.50): " + pizza [0] + "\n" +
         "Cheese Pizza ($9.50): " + pizza [1] + "\n" +
         "Veggie Pizza ($9.50): " + pizza [2] + "\n" + 
         "Supreme Pizza ($9.50): " + pizza [3] + "\n" +
         "Pepperoni Pizza ($9.50): " + pizza [4] + "\n" +
         "Meat-Lovers Pizza ($15.50): " + pizza [5] + "\n" +
         "Chicken Pizza ($15.50): " + pizza [6] + "\n" +
         "Prawn Pizza ($15.50): " + pizza [7]);  
     

  if (totalNumber >12) {          // Limit for total amount of Pizzas ordered
      alert("There is a limit of 12 pizzas per order. - PRESS 'Prevent this page from creating     additional dialogs' THEN PRESS 'cancel order' AND THEN RE-ORDER! - Current total is: " +totalNumber);
  } else 
      alert("Total number of pizzas ordered: " + totalNumber); //Total amount of pizzas ordered
  calculate(totalGourmet,totalPlain)  //Begins calculation function
}


function calculate(totalGourmet,totalPlain)    //Function for the cost of the order
{
    orderTotalPrice = (totalPlain*pizzaPrice + totalGourmet*pizzaPriceGourmet);  //order total+ amount of pizzas ordered * pizza price
    var pizzaDelivery = prompt('Would you like your order to be delivered for $5, or for pick up?    -Type in "1" for delivery, and "0" for pickup.') //asks if you want your order to be delivered or pickup
    orderTotalPrice = (orderTotalPrice + (pizzaDelivery*pizzaDeliveryPrice)); // calculates the total cost with/without the delivery cost
    alert("Total cost of pizzas is: $" + orderTotalPrice.toFixed(2) );  //Display order cost as "$"0.00 (2 decimal points)
    if (pizzaDelivery == '1'){
        var response = prompt("Please enter your address: ")
        alert("Your pizza should be delivered within the next 25 minutes, to this address:   " +response)
         alert("Thank you for ordering with Pete's Pizzas " +customerName)
         alert("If anything goes wrong we will contact you on your number: " +customerNumber)
     alert("The pizzas you ordered are: " +fullOrder) 
         alert("Your order details are: " +customerName +"\n" +customerNumber +"\n" +response)
         alert("To exit, just click 'ok' and then close down the program!")
    } else if (pizzaDelivery == '0'){
         alert("Your order will be ready for pickup in 15 minutes!")
         alert("Thank you for ordering with Pete's Pizzas " +customerName)
         alert("If anything goes wrong we will contact you on your number: " +customerNumber)
     alert("The pizzas you ordered are: " +fullOrder); 
         alert("Your order details are: " +customerName +"\n" +customerNumber)
         alert("To exit, just click 'ok' and then close down the program!")
    }
}

</script>

<body>
<h1> Welcome to Pete's Pizza! </h1>
<p> Please follow the prompts to place your order. </p>
<h2> Menu: </h2>
<h3>($9.50) Hawaiian, Cheese, Veggie, supreme, pepperoni.</h3>
<h3>($15.50) meat-lovers, chicken, prawn. </h3>
<p><b>BE AWARE</b> that there is a $5 charge for deliveries. </p>
<p> (Please note : Maximum 12 pizzas per Order ) </p>

<form name ="form">                              
     
<input type="text" name= "hawaiian" > Hawaiian Pizza <br>
<input type="text" name= "cheese" > Cheese Pizza <br>
<input type="text" name= "veggie" > Veggie Pizza <br>
<input type="text" name= "supreme" > Supreme Pizza <br>
<input type="text" name= "pepperoni" > Pepperoni Pizza <br>
<input type="text" name= "meatlovers" > MeatLovers Pizza <br>
<input type="text" name= "chicken" > Chicken Pizza <br>
<input type="text" name= "prawn" > Prawn Pizza <br>

<input type="button" value="order now" onClick="order()">
<input type="button" value="cancel order" onClick="window.location.reload()">
</form>



<i> If you need to cancel the order press the 'Prevent this page from creating     additional dialogs' button, then press the "cancel order" button. (This will take you back to the begging of the program.)  </i>
</body>   
    
</html>
```